Embedding plotly (r) graph on website, updating through API call?
My question: I am wondering about embedding a plotly bar graph in a website. The graph would pull data from an API call, cached (so it calls a maximum once a minute). I'm assuming this is possible, without shiny? Or am I missing something? It does not need to be interactive beyond what plotly offers (hover text, etc).
Past experience: I have built and embedded plotly (in R) graphs on a github.io website before without going through chart studio, but this used a static dataset. I have also built and embedded shiny (in R) apps on a github.io website before--again, static dataset, processing through htmltools and embedding as an iframe. I've done basic pull requests with APIs and played with data there, but I have not included an API call into something I've embedded in a website.
I haven't included code here because I didn't think it's needed as the issue isn't with the code, but a more theoretical/process question (or my understanding of embedding apps made in R). I can add some if necessary (it's a basic bar graph that pulls in data from an API, it works on my end).
What I did already:

I have read through as much on plotly-R as I can find, as well as looking through stack overflow and also doing a bunch of internet searches.
I can see how to cache API calls on shiny, but can't find much on doing this with plotly-R.
0 I can find information on updating shiny apps that use plotly with a cached API call, and this answer leads me to believe doing it through shiny would just make it easier to embed.
Still...I have it sorted as a plotly graph now, but I worry I'm missing something significant if I try to move forward. (This could just be my own anxieties and insecurity taking up too much space!)

